# How to change lib path for "go build"

Tags: go, ncurses

I'm trying to work with goncurses.  On Centos 6 the ncurses library is old (5.7, wants 5.9), so I built ncurses from source and installed it into /usr/lib, /usr/include, etc.

How do I tell "go get" to run against the stuff in /usr/lib instead of the system stuff in /lib?

This is my currenty output:

```
$ go get -v code.google.com/p/goncurses
code.google.com/p/goncurses
# code.google.com/p/goncurses
/tmp/go-build076024492/code.google.com/p/goncurses/_obj/goncurses.o: In function `ncurses_is_subwin':
src/code.google.com/p/goncurses/goncurses.c:71: undefined reference to `is_subwin'
/tmp/go-build076024492/code.google.com/p/goncurses/_obj/goncurses.o: In function `ncurses_is_pad':
src/code.google.com/p/goncurses/goncurses.c:63: undefined reference to `is_pad'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried different variations on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib` and `-ccflags = '-I /usr/lib'` with out any change in behavior.

I know it's a simple question, but my google-fu is failing me right now.

Comment: that looks like a linking issue, try with `-ldflag "-L/usr/lib -lncursesw"` maybe.

Comment: nope, `go get -v -ldflags "-L/usr/lib" code.google.com/p/goncurses` has same output

Comment: You either have a messed up ncurses install or using an outdated version, you should use their bug tracker if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `goncurses` package is relying on `pkg-config` to get the proper paths for building.

If you can get `pkg-config` to output the correct paths for ncurses on your system -- go will do the right thing from there. Your other option is of course to fork the goncurses code, and edit the `#cgo` directives in the source.

Comment: All right, well that at least gave me the direction, even if it still made me find the answer myself. 

This sets up a local directory for pkg-config and tells configure to put the .pc files there after installing the ncurses libs into /usr/local/ 

`mkdir ~/local-pkg-config-libdir && PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=~/local-pkg-config-libdir ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-pc-files --with-pkg-config`

This tells pkg-config to use that alternate config directory when it builds the go executable. 

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/local-pkg-config-libdir/ go get -v code.google.com/p/goncurses `

Comment: Nice. I was able to do the same thing on OS X.  I put the details in a separate self-answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975235/how-to-build-goncurses-on-os-x-centos-6/