# How to build goncurses on os x, centos 6

Tags: macos, go, centos, ncurses

OS X, Centos 6 and Debian Squeeze all come with v5.7 of ncurses, but the go wrapper "goncurses" requires 5.9.  Trying to build it on any of those platforms will give you an error like this:

```
$ go get -v code.google.com/p/goncurses
code.google.com/p/goncurses
# code.google.com/p/goncurses 
/tmp/go-build527609801/code.google.com/p/goncurses/_obj/goncurses.o: 
In function 'ncurses_is_subwin':src/code.google.com/p/goncurses/goncurses.c:71: undefined reference to `is_subwin'
/tmp/go-build527609801/code.google.com/p/goncurses/_obj/goncurses.o: 
In function 'ncurses_is_pad':src/code.google.com/p/goncurses/goncurses.c:63: undefined reference to `is_pad'
```

You can use homebrew to install ncurses v5.9 on os x, and build from source into /usr/local/ on linux, but how do you get `go` to use your upgraded ncurses when building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JimB answered my other question [How to change lib path for "go build"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879205/how-to-change-lib-path-for-go-build/) with a suggestion to leverage pkg-config, which solution will look like this:

On CentOS 6 you can build ncurses from source like this, which will put the .pc files that drive pkg-config into your own directory instead of /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/

```
mkdir ~/local-pkg-config
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=~/local-pkg-config ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-pc-files --with-pkg-config
make && make install
```

On OS X you can install ncurses from homebrew. Homebrew usually puts .pc files along with the package, e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.34.1/lib/pkgconfig/pango.pc`. For some reason homebrew doesn't have any .pc files with its ncurses, but I successfully grabbed the CentOS ones into ~/local-pkg-config and changed them to suit:

```
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
-prefix=/usr/local/
+prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/5.9/
 exec_prefix=${prefix}
 libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
-includedir=${prefix}/include/ncurses
+includedir=${prefix}/include
 major_version=5
 version=5.9.20110404
```

Now on either platform you're set up to go get the goncurses package:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/local-pkg-config/ go get -v code.google.com/p/goncurses
```

Answer (score 2):

This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/giuliano108/57d0532e84570a781f85) is a modified `ncurses` formula for Homebrew that adds the `.pc` files to the keg. If you install `ncurses` with it, use the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to point pkg-config to the `.pc` files, before calling `go build` or `go run`.

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ncurses/5.9/lib/pkgconfig
$ go run your_ncurses_program.go
```